# child div stretching across page

Tags: jquery, html, css

My issue, really annoying - *check the black bar*:

[image]

Trying to make it so the black bar stretches across whole page.
Does anyone know how to do this? Been trying it for a while now.
Any help is appreciated. :D

My code:

```
    <div id="forum-header">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Forum Tutorial</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul id="forum-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com/community/">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com/purchase/">Purchase</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com/support/">Support</a></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

My css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;  
}
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#forum-wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
#forum-header {
    font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #3B6C8E;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
#forum-navbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#forum-navbar li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #444;
}
#forum-navbar li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you have set the `li` to a fixed width, so they are taking total of 600px only....to make it stretch to the 100% width, you have to make them *occupy* the whole width.

Also, use `clear:both` after `ul` to clear out the `float`

and to make it 100% of the width, assign `li` `25%` width

[**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rrz1u15k/2/)

```
#forum-navbar li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%; /* add this */
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #444;
}
```

**OR**

replace the `background: #444;` to `ul` instead of `li`..this will also make it stretch to whole width without changing the `li`s default width

[**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rrz1u15k/3/)

Comment: That didn't fix it :S See, I'm still left with this http://prntscr.com/4gjgth I don't want that. I want the black bar to go across. And yes it is outside of the container so Idk why it doesnt work

Comment: @user1944027 : set a `border:1px solid red` to `#forum-navbar` and then show me the snapshot...i assume `ul` has gotta do something or check my updated answer...

Comment: @user1944027 : ok..perfect,this shows that `ul` is stretching to the whole width, then move the `background: #444;` to `#forum-navbar` that would solve your problem...see this is happening because you have applied bg-color to `li`'s,and it would only stretch to the whole width if the `li`s are stretching...moving bg-color to `ul` is not a problem for you..is it? :)

Comment: Not sure what I did and I tried using ctrl+z but now I have this http://prntscr.com/4gjj0z LMFAO I don't know how to fix >..

Comment: @user1944027 : you removed a `<div class="clr"></div>` just before the closing `<\ul>` so `float`s collapsed the height...did you place `background: #444;` to `#forum-navbar`?

Comment: @user1944027 : glad i could help...drop a comment if you still need help!! :)

Comment: I do have one more. I'm using jQuery and some javascript and my dropdown is positioned to the right when its supposed to be centered. Look: http://prntscr.com/4gjkib Looks ugly I want to fix it :P

Comment: @user1944027 : hmm...possible to give a fiddle of it?? This is solvable easily if i get to see the code! :)

Comment: @user1944027 : [**set a negative margin**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4qbLegL/2/) ..let me know if this will work for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create an extra DIV (with id "container-navbar") as given below

```
body {
    margin: 0;  
}
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#forum-wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
#forum-header {
    font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #3B6C8E;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
#container-navbar {
    background: #444;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
}
#forum-navbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#forum-navbar li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #444;
}
#forum-navbar li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;  
}


<div id="forum-header">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Forum Tutorial</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container-navbar">
    <ul id="forum-navbar">
        <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com/community/">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com/purchase/">Purchase</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com/support/">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working solution @ http://jsfiddle.net/Midhun52/h95bttw0/

Move the ul to the div and apply the style below

**HTML**

```
<div id="forum-header">
    <div class="container">
         <h2>Forum Tutorial</h2>

    </div>
</div>
<ul id="forum-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com/community/">Community</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com/purchase/">Purchase</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mineforums.com/support/">Support</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.mystyle{
   background-color: #444;
   height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this example. In this fiddle I have fixed your issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yunus_Aslam/bhs6meno/

I think the issue is with the css

```
#forum-header
```

Go ahead and check out the fiddle.

Comment: I copied but I have also edited that. Just check out the difference in your html page and mine.

Comment: I think you forgot to scroll the view area in your fiddle.. :)